# Exponential improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

How to calculate $$\int_0^\infty \frac{5x}{\theta}\left(1-\text{e}^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}\right)^4\text{e}^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}\text{d}x$$
I have done this one by expanding the terms and integrate by parts. But it seems to much calculation. Any other ways?

Answer (score 2):

Let $t:=1-\exp\left(-\dfrac{x}{\theta}\right)$,
$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{5x}{\theta}\left(1-\exp\left(-\dfrac{x}{\theta}\right)\right)^4\exp\left(-\frac{x}{\theta}\right)\text{d}x=-5\theta\int_0^1\ln(1-t)t^4\text{d}t$$
The Taylor Series of $\ln(1-t)$ is $\displaystyle -\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{t^n}{n}$, hence
$\begin{align*}
\text{LHS}&=5\theta\sum_{n\geq 1}\int_0^1\dfrac{t^{n+4}}{n}\text{d}t=5\theta\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{n(n+5)}=\theta\sum_{n\geq 1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+5}\right\}
\\&=\theta\left(\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{5}\right)
\end{align*}$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}x\mathrm e^{-x}\mathrm dx=1$ hence, using the change of variable $x\to a x$, for every $a\gt0$, one gets $\int\limits_0^{+\infty}x\mathrm e^{-ax}\mathrm dx=\frac1{a^2}$. Using the change of variable $x\to\theta x$ and expanding the fourth power in the integral $I$ to compute, one gets $I=\theta J$ with
$$
J=5\sum_{k=0}^4{4\choose k}(-1)^k\int_0^{+\infty}x\mathrm e^{-(k+1)x}\mathrm dx=5\sum_{k=0}^4{4\choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}.
$$
Replacing $5{4\choose k}\frac1{k+1}$ by ${5\choose k+1}$ and using the change of variable $k\to k+1$, one gets
$$
J=\sum_{k=1}^5{5\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k},
$$
that is,
$$
I=\theta\left(\frac51-\frac{10}2+\frac{10}3-\frac54+\frac15\right).
$$
An alternative formula for $I$ stems from the decomposition
$$
{5\choose k}=\sum_{i\leqslant4}{i\choose k-1}.
$$
Hence $J=J_0+J_1+J_2+J_3+J_4$ where
$$
J_i=\sum_{k\geqslant1}{i\choose k-1}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\frac1{i+1}\sum_{k\geqslant1}(-1)^{k+1}{i+1\choose k},
$$
that is,
$$
J_i=\frac1{i+1}(1-(1-1)^{i+1})=\frac1{i+1}.
$$
Thus, $I$ is also
$$
I=\theta\sum_{i=0}^4\frac1{i+1}.
$$